# command using awk only outputting 1 line

Tags: bash, awk, matching

I have two files:

file 1:

```
rs3094315 1 0 742429 G A
rs12124819 1 0 766409 G A
rs2272756 1 0 871896 A G
rs3128126 1 0 952073 G A
rs3934834 1 0 995669 A G
rs3766192 1 0 1007060 G A
```

file 2:

```
rs12565286 1 0 711153 C G
rs12138618 1 0 740098 A G
rs3094315 1 0 742429 G A
rs3131968 1 0 744055 A G
rs12562034 1 0 758311 A G
rs2905035 1 0 765522 A G
rs12124819 1 0 766409 G A
rs2980319 1 0 766985 A T
rs4040617 1 0 769185 G A
rs2980300 1 0 775852 T C
rs4951864 1 0 787889 C T
rs12132517 1 0 788664 A G
rs950122 1 0 836727 C G
rs2272756 1 0 871896 A G
rs3128126 1 0 952073 G A
rs3121561 1 0 980243 T C
rs3813193 1 0 988364 C G
rs4075116 1 0 993492 C T
rs3934834 1 0 995669 T C
rs3766193 1 0 1007033 C G
rs3766192 1 0 1007060 C T
rs3766191 1 0 1007450 T C
```

The files have many more matches in the first column after these shown here, there are about 500k lines in both files.
I'm trying to use the following command to find matches in the first column (rs####) and if found, put the matches on one line in a new folder.

```
 awk 'NF==FNR{s=$1; a[s]=$0; next} a[$1]{print $0" "a[$1]}' file1 file2 > mergedfiles
```

However, this command only gives 1 match (shown below) in mergedfiles and I just can't figure out what is going wrong. It's probably something really easy :s. Thanks in advance if you are able to clear this problem up.

```
rs3766192 1 0 1007060 C T rs3766192 1 0 1007060 G A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
NR==FNR
```

Your condition only picks up the sixth line (because there are 6 fields in the first file)!

Comment: And that was it. Thanks! Do you reckon it is best to delete this question since it was so easy to answer, or leave it up?

Comment: It had me bemused for a minute or two. It is so easy to be suckered into reading what ought to be there rather than what is there.  You did a nice job on presenting the question — inputs, actual and expected outputs, honest attempt at solving the problem. Good job!

Comment: +1 for reading what many of us couldn't. @Xizam: Don't delete but mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: I wanted to, but I had to wait for 10 minutes before I could. Done now.